# Integration of live streaming video in PHP

Tags: youtube-api

How can I integrate live streaming video functionality in my Website likewise youtube? I am just a PHP programmer only. What other technologies I have to use to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just using a standard YouTube embed on your page? If you visit the YouTube watch page for a specific live stream, there should be a link on that page for the embed code you could use.